# How to translate "Critically Examine“？

Tags: translation, word-choice

I am trying to translate some academic essay:

> By critically examining the original records of the history of Chinese Bible translation....

Google translates "critically" to "批判地", but I don't think it's suitable here because "批判地" in Chinese conveys a negative sense and it usually implies the subject is superior, which I don't think is the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Critical - Characterized by careful evaluation and judgment (審慎)

critically examining 審慎地檢驗

Answer (score 1):

"critically" also means  "analytically"

**Critically** examining --> **分析性地**检查   (to check analytically)